# QC-LDPC Decoder - Is it a codeword?

Tags: forward-error-correction

I'm designing a QC-LDPC decoder in VHDL. It uses a layered decoding method - only a single block row of parity equations is evaluated each iteration (the bit values are still updated every iteration). Bit values are stored as log-likelihoods with the sign representing the respective bit symbol.

A valid codeword is indicated by all parity equations being satisfied. I only ever evaluate a single block row of parity equations. What I want to know is how much information I need to gather to be certain that the current bit values represent a valid codeword.

Is it enough that each parity equation in $N_b$ successive rows was satisfied, where $N_b$ is the total number of block rows. To my mind that is not enough - bit values can change signs even when every equation is satisfied? Or am I wrong here? If true this might invalidate previously correct block rows.

If this is true, then I can only guarantee a codeword is correct by ensuring that for $N_b$ successive rows, all parity equations were satisfied and that no bits changed sign.

Am I missing something simple? Or is this the way I need to go about this?